# HubL template language list logic

Tags: python, django-templates, jinja2, hubspot

I'm working in a cms called Hubspot using a templating language called HubL. Hubspot is written in python and HubL closely resembles Jinja2 or Django templates. Usually when I need to find an answer I can search for the answer in jinja2 and find what I need. I have been trying to figure this out for a few weeks now though but I think the issue is to specific.

Hubspot hosts blogs. These blogs accessible under the "contents" variable in a blog template or by using a pre-defined function on any other template type:

```
{% for content in contents %}
    {# output blog list #}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% set test_list = blog_recent_posts('default', 250) %}
{% for post in test_list %}
    {# output blog list #}
{% endfor %}
```

Each blog post has a topics_list variable. this variable contains a list of topics set to a specific blog. you would use it inside the blog list loop by looping through it.

```
{% for content in contents %}
    {% for topic in content.topic_list %}
        {{ topic.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you just call topic_list:

```
{% for content in contents %}
    {{ content.topic_list }}
{% endfor %}
```

it outputs:

```
[topic1, topic2]
```

The issue I am having is that I need to exclude posts with specific topics from the main list. I can use a nested for loop and a condition to exclude then from output:

```
{% for content in contents %}
   {% for topic in content.topic_list %}
      {% unless topic.name = 'topic 1' %}
          {# ouput if condition is not met #}
      {% endunless %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is messy. It loops through the blogs and at each index loops through the topics. if a topic matches the defined topic then it is omitted from output. This works, except that it doesn't omit the blog from contents. The blogs that are block from output still exist at their index. If I limit the output to 3 blogs, for instance, and one of the three blogs has a topic that matches 'topic 1', the space isn't filled with the next blog in line, the space is just left blank.

Actually what this is doing is outputting the markup for a list item for each topic of each blog as long as that topic doesn't match the blocked topic so it will duplicate posts if more than one topic is present.

I thought about using the predefined function, which you can use to define a specific topic you want posts for, so I looped through a global list of topics tied to the blog, and if the topic doesn't equal blocked topics it runs the topic specific function:

```
{% set mlist = [] %}
{% set global_topics = blog_topics('default', 250) %}

{% for gtopic in global_topics %}
    {% unless gtopic == 'topic1' %}
        {% set wlist = blog_recent_posts('default', 250, gtopic.slug) %}

        {% set mlist2 = mlist.append(wlist) %}

    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}

{% for post in mlist[0] %}

    <strong>{{post.name }}</strong><br>
    {% for topic in post.topic_list %}
        {{topic.name}}<br>
    {% endfor %}<br> <br>

{% endfor %}
```

I'm honestly surprised I got this to work period but it combines the list created from each topic and outputs them. The only issue is that because multiple topics are applied to the topic lists, while it doesn't include a list created from the blocked topic, it still includes blogs containing the blocked topic from lists created using the second or third (etc.) topic on the blog post.

The simplest solution would be to create a new list by filtering post by if the topic is **IN** the topic_list but this doesn't work.

```
{% set mlist = [] %}
{% for content in contents %}
    {% unless 'topic-1' is in content.topic_list %}
        {% set mlist2 = mlist.append(content) %}
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

but I guess you can't use 'in' like this? it doesn't work.

Please keep in mind that I understand that this would be a non-issue if I did this filtering in python directly instead of in the template, and I understand that logic shouldn't be handled in the template, but Hubspot doesn't allow custom python scripting or any back end capability so this is what I have to work with. Can anyone think of a creative solution?